# Convert Entity Framework DB Connection to use Azure Identity using Powershell Credentials

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-powershell, azure-identity

We have an application that is setup to use EntityFramework. I need to update that application to access the database using Azure Identity. Basically I need to do the following:

1. Get the access token using AzurePowershell Credentials
2. Create the SQL Connection using that access token
3. Add the token to the connection and return it to the caller

Here's what I have so far (but I know i'm missing alot of things here coz I am getting compilation errors). I was looking for some examples to do this but wasn't successful.

```
public static DbConnection CreateConnection( string efConnectionString )
        {

            var credential = new AzurePowerShellCredential();
            System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;
            TokenRequestContext requestContext = "https://database.windows.net/.default";
            string accessToken = AzurePowerShellCredential.GetToken( "https://database.windows.net/.default", cancellationToken );

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder( efConnectionString );
            //create sql connection

            using( SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection( efConnectionString ) )
            {
                    sqlConn.AccessToken = accessToken;
            return sqlConn;
            }
```

For starters the requestContext doesn't like being set up as a string and I'm trying to figure out the best way to add the token to the connection string and send it back successfully. Also, the AzurePowerShellCredential.GetToken doesn't like the string that I am passing with the database address.
My Connection string that is coming in looks like this:

```
"Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Database=databasename;User ID=UserID@servername;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
```

In order for this to work successfully, I will be ommitting the userid and password from the above connections string so it can be replaced by the AzureCredentials.

I really appreciate any help that can be provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The only thing I would suggest is to use [`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) which would allow you to use different authentication flows for the database.

As for a connection string it's format can be following:

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var connString = "Server=tcp:<your-server-name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database-name>;";

var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var token = credential
    .GetToken(
        new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" })
    );

using var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.AccessToken = token.Token;

conn.Open();
```

---

One more thing you should think about is access token renewal. EntityFramework caches database connections so the token might expire while the connection is alive. As an option I can suggest you to use existing solution like in [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-entityframework-dotnet) if you have an ASP.NET app or try to reverse-engineer token update logic like in `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-default-authentication))